# Disabling Network Manager in CentOS 7 and enabling network.service causes 'Network is unreachable' error

Tags: networking, centos, centos-7

I installed CentOS 7 using the minimal ISO on my Proxmox VPS, configured my ifcfg-eth0 file. After that I was able to use yum update, ping 8.8.8.8, connect via SSH, etc.

After following [this guide](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Disable+Network+Manager) to disable network manager - I'm not longer able to do anything network related, including pinging 8.8.8.8 (I get 'connect: Network is unreachable')

My ifcfg-eth0:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
PROXY_METHOD="none"
BROWSER_ONLY="no"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="eth0"
UUID=...
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT="yes"
HWADDR=My Virtual Mac from OVH
IPADDR=IP assigned to VPS
PREFIX="24"
GATEWAY=Correct gateway for my OVH server
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `network-manager` is disabled, your resolv.conf file is not automatically generated anymore. You can just create one on `/etc/resolv.conf`.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Nope, /etc/resolv.conf is configured and I can't ping IP addresses. Thank you though

Comment: Check your current interfaces if you have an assigned ip address on your box.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: You can check by entering `ip a`

Comment: lo is inet 127.0.0.1/8, eth0 is inet IP/24

Comment: Can you ping your gateway? i.e 192.168.1.1 or similar.

Comment: I can't ping my gateway (At least the IP I think is my gateway), but I can ping 127.0.0.1 and the eth0 IP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83722/discussion-between-sudo-and-jon).